# React-router + react-bootstrap

Tags: react-router, react-bootstrap

How do I merge the two to create a vertical menu? I've got a basic routing setup (which works and gets rendered as a standard horizontal menu):

```
<div>
      <Link className="p5" to='/'>Home</Link>
      <Link className="p5" to='/Gallery'>Gallery</Link>
      <Link className="p5" to='/Contact'>Contact</Link>
</div>
```

From react-bootstrap docs, there's this example for a vertical Nav element:

```
function handleSelect(selectedKey) {
  alert('selected ' + selectedKey);
}

const navInstance = (
  <Nav bsStyle="pills" stacked activeKey={1} onSelect={handleSelect}>
    <NavItem eventKey={1} href="/home">NavItem 1 content</NavItem>
    <NavItem eventKey={2} title="Item">NavItem 2 content</NavItem>
    <NavItem eventKey={3} disabled>NavItem 3 content</NavItem>
  </Nav>
);
```

I'm confused how to get both of them together? I managed to put them together without using react-bootstrap, just normal bootstrap like below, but that defeats the purpose of using react-bootstrap.

```
<ul className="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
      <li className="active"><Link className="p5" to='/'>Home</Link></li>
      <li><Link className="p5" to='/Gallery'>Gallery</Link></li>
      <li><Link className="p5" to='/Contact'>Contact</Link></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Use the react-router-boostrap project: https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-router-bootstrap

Answer (score 4):

I use `react-router-bootstrap` in my project, really helping, to install do:

`npm install -S react-router-bootstrap`

> **Usage**
>
> Wrap your React Bootstrap element in a `<LinkContainer>` to make it
>   behave like a React Router `<Link>`
>
> `<LinkContainer>` accepts same parameters as React Router's `<NavLink>`
>
> Please note that by default React Router will match any location that
>   contains path specified in to prop. To make `<LinkContainer>` to match
>   the location exactly, set exact prop to true or use
>   `<IndexLinkContainer>` instead.

and this is the example of the usage:

```
<Button href="/example">Foo</Button>
```

Using react-router-bootstrap:

```
<LinkContainer to="/example">
  <Button>Foo</Button>
</LinkContainer>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using react-bootstrap too and Redux, another option you can take is doing this programmatically, I think I did not want to use Link because a button looked quite better than that. If you are using react-router, you can use the context to access your history.

```
<Button className="p5" onClick={this.handleClick}>Gallery</Button>
```

> HandleClick Function:

```
handleClick(e) {
    //this.props.history.push('/Gallery');
    this.context.router.push('/Gallery');
    //this.props...();  // You can fire your action here
  }
```

> If you need to fire an action before the component is umounted you can do it there.